# Is there named region or selection?

Tags: vim

I know <kbd>gv</kbd> shows the last selection, but can I give the selection a name, so that later I can get the selection through its name? It's ok if the region is remembered by row and column.

Comment: You can use registers, see `:h y`.

Answer (score 4):

Selections can't be named, but positions can. If the selection is gone:

```
`<ma`>mb
```

Saves the selection start and end to `a` and `b` markers. (The marker `<` is the selection start, `>` is selection end; we simply assign them to any custom markers, `a-z`.) If the selection is current, you can even do this (but pay attention to if you're top or bottom):

```
mboma
```

(`o` means "go to the other side of the selection"). Then, later,

```
`av`b
```

Reselects the selection corresponding to `a` and `b` markers.